# Need to change selected item in dropdown list when selected item in another dropdown list changes

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

I have a windows form application with two Combo boxes (Dropdownlist style). The first combo box gets the data from a List of AppTable object, like so:

```
foreach (AppTable table in appTableList)
            cbxSelectName.Items.Add(table.App);
```

I have set up a trigger for when the selected item in this dropdown is changed:

```
this.cbxSelectName.SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(cbxSelectName_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

And finally, here is the definition of the method the trigger calls. Please note, the value in tbxNewWikiWord textbox changes as the selected item is changed. However, the same does not happen in the second dropdown list ( cbxUpdateAppType):

```
private void cbxSelectName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AppTable table in appTableList)
        {
            if (table.App == cbxSelectName.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                this.tbxNewWikiWord.Text = table.WikiWord;
                this.cbxUpdateAppType.SelectedItem = table.Type;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

This is how AppTable looks:

```
class AppTable
{
    public string App { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string WikiWord { get; set; }

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you filling `cbxUpdateAppType` with the contents that appear in `table.Type`? Please post the code that fills `cbxUpdateAppType`.

Comment: table.Type can hold one of three values: Service, Task or Application. However, I fill cbxUpdateAppType manually with these three values, because if I fill it from table.Type in a loop, it gets the same values multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding values to cbxUpdateAppType from the AppTable object fixed it. I'm not sure why since in either case, I was adding Strings.

I just needed to check for duplicates so I don't end up with multiple instances of the same value in my dropdown box.

```
foreach (AppTable table in appTableList)
        {
            if (!cbxUpdateAppType.Items.Contains(table.Type))
                cbxUpdateAppType.Items.Add(table.Type);
        }
```